# Is a direct connection between a react native app and firebase realtime database good practice?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, mobile, architecture

I am building a small mobile app with react native.

My initial thoughts were, that it is safer to communicate with the database over a running nodejs backend server in order to avoid security risks due to direct connection between mobile and DB.

Now i want the clients to receive realtime updates from the DB and the only way that i can think of, is to connect the mobile app to the firebase realtime database and subscribe to changes without having any backend server between it.

Is this a good way to go or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether something is a good way is typically opinionated. But it is definitely possible to build a secure app that directly accesses the database, because you can control access to the data with server-side security rules.

For more on this, I recommend checking out my answer to [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37482366/209103)

It might also be useful to check this video where we [live-code a secure voting app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwrUezKCc34&feature=youtu.be).